# Existence of two continuous functions which are independent as random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are two continuous non-constant functions. Does there exists $A,B\in \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}$ (Borel sigma field)such that $\lambda(f^{-1}(A)\cap g^{-1}(B))=0$ but $\lambda(f^{-1}(A))>0$ and $\lambda(g^{-1}(B))>0$. Here $\lambda(\cdot)$ is the lebesgue measure.

I was trying to come up with examples of two continuous functions $f,g$ so that they are independent as random variable over $([0,1],\lambda,\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]})$. The above example will be sufficient to show such existence. But I can’t prove it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not true as stated, a counter example is if $f=g$ are constant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right constant function doesn't work here. What I meant was does this hold for non constant functions? I have also changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Look at the paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321827 Stochastic Independence and Space-Filling Curves by John A. R. Holbrook, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 88, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1981), pp. 426-432. The author proved that if any non-constant continuous functions are independent, then they are coordinates of space-filling curve.

Comment: Look also at https://mathoverflow.net/q/76727