# Continuous functions as random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, independence

Let $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\text{Leb})$ be a probability space. Are there two non-constant continuous function $f$ and $g$ which, when viewed as random variables, are independent?

I suspect that this is impossible, but I have no idea how to prove it. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3509176/413376